# Can SAS use SFTP method to import a file from external network

Tags: sas

I was going through the documentation for sas on sftp:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0xln1fiwsr340n1xxf4mkmfxp6f.htm

Here it is mentioned that we can import files from differant systems over a network. Is it possible to import the files present on adifferant network through sftp method.

I have a requirement where i need to load a file in sas after fetching the file directly which will be present in another network(outside my organisation).

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

As long as the SFTP server in question is reachable from within your network, SAS shoud be able to connect to it, just like any other SFTP client. However, many corporate networks block SFTP connections, so you may need to contact your network administrator.